# Convert from Byte Array to String and compare against another String (java)

Tags: java, string, arrays

I have a UDP server/client that sends and receive information. The `Client` will send example `"TEST"` to the server, the server will receive `"TEST"` in a `byte[]` array representation and convert it to `String` using the `String(byte[])` constructor. I then need to compare the new `String` received against another string using the `equalsIgnoreCase` method. But it's not working...

Here's a sample of my code :

```
DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
//Client sent "TEST"
String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData(), "UTF-8");
System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);
System.out.println(sentence.equalsIgnoreCase("TEST")); //This gives me FALSE
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is not working? Exception, expected vs. actual output?

Comment: What does `System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);` print?

Comment: System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence) will print "RECEIVED: TEST"
But when comparing sentence against "TEST" the result is false

Comment: Are you sure you have no spaces in your input string, in `sentence`?

Comment: Could you report the hexdump (you can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/convert-from-byte-array-to-hex-string-in-java) to print hexdump) of `sentence` and  `receivePacket.getData()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the string in `sentence` is not `"TEST"` but something that *looks like* `"TEST"` when you display it.  The most likely strings are:

- `" TEST"` or `"TEST "`
- `"TEST\n"`

But it is also possible that you have a [homoglyph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph) in either the client string, or your server code.

---

> Alright so I just found out using sentence.length() that sentence is 1024 characters long...if I take a substring of it, specifically sentence.substring(0,4).

Ah.  So the problem is (probably) that you are ignoring the size of the received packet, and including the entire buffer array in the string.

The most correct way to extract the string is:

```
new String(receivePacket.getData(),
           receivePacket.getOffset(),
           receivePacket.getLength(), "UTF-8");
```

... though I think that the offset is going to be zero, given the previous statements.

(But it is also possible that the client is sending the NUL bytes ... in which case, you will also need to change things on the client side.)

Comment: Alright so I just found out using `sentence.length()` that `sentence` is 1024 characters long...if I take a substring of it, specifically `sentence.substring(0,4)` the comparison gives me true.

Comment: Any way to cut out all those extra blank characters after or before the word "TEST" for example?

Comment: Check out the _DatagramPacket.getOffset()_ and _DatagramPacket.getLength()_ methods.

Answer (score 1):

Create string object like this way

```
String msg = new String(receiveData, 0, receivePacket.length);
```

instead of

```
String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData(), "UTF-8");
```

In your code will getting the data but it have extra content too. For example in your receiveData size set to 10 which will be reading from your packet object. Now for "Test" it will be use 4 block in your receiveData and rest of block i.e. 6 are null so that all will be use in your sentence object too. Thats why sentence will not match.

For test just print your sentence object first like this way

```
Log.e("Sentence",""+sentence);
```

Comment: `System.out.println(msg)` is giving me TEST, but the comparison between `msg` and "TEST" are false still

Answer (score 1):

I think receiveData is longer than 4, so trailing bytes are also contained in the converted String. You should cut off the trailing bytes(byte 0) when you new String.

Answer (score 0):

`"TEST "` and `"TEST"` are not equal. 
Verify string length.

```
System.out.println(sentence.length());
```

To remove spaces using:

```
sentence = sentence.trim();
```

Comment: Tried the `trim` command, still returns 1024 character string

Answer (score 0):

From [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html) use:

```
String received = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());
```

to get string from received packet; in your case you will have:

```
String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData(), 0, receivePacket.getLength());
```